# Is it possible to pass parameter and dataprovider for same test method in TestNG

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider

```
/* testdataprovider will return the test2 and test3 parameter value */
@Parameters("test1")
@Test(dataProvider = "testdataprovider")
public void testMethod(String test1, String test2, String test3){}
```

Comment: Yes i think it should be possible . Why dont you just try and find out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently (the latest TestNG version is 6.9.9), it is not possible to do what you expect.
The reason is TestNG is not able to understand which parameter comes from the data provider and which one comes from `@Parameters`.

I expected that is possible to add `@Parameters` on a `@DataProvider` method, but [it looks like it is not possible for the moment](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/internal/MethodInvocationHelper.java#L102-L123).